# Jupyter Notebook opening error with Terminal

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am always using terminal command `jupyter notebook` to open my notebook until oneday after several libraries were installed. I don't whether it does any harm, but it cannot be open anyway. Here is the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 43, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .environment import Environment
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/defaults.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .filters import FILTERS as DEFAULT_FILTERS  # noqa: F401
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/filters.py", line 13, in <module>
    from markupsafe import soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py)
```

Please help me fix the problem, thx.